# Can't Remove WM_TIMER message

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, timer

I have a problem with my code, and after several hours, I can't seem to figure it out...

Problem: I'm trying to attempt to connect to a server every ten seconds. When the timer first elapses, the callback function is called just fine, but then it is called again immediately (without waiting ten seconds), and it keeps being called again and again and again repeatedly, as if the timer message is not getting removed from the queue. Can anyone help?

The timer is set here:

```
SConnect::SConnect()
{
    hSimConnect = NULL;
    Attempt();
    SetTimer(hMainWindow, reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(this), 10000, (TIMERPROC)TimerProc);
}
```

The (only) application message loop is here:

```
    while (true)
    {
        PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;

        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        //UPDATES
        pSCObj->Update();
        manager.Update();
        Sleep(50);
    }
```

And the timer callback function is here:

```
void CALLBACK SConnect::TimerProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime){
    SConnect *pSC = reinterpret_cast<SConnect *>(idEvent);
    MSG wMsg;

    if (!pSC->connected)
    pSC->Attempt();
    else{
        pSC->connected = false;
    }
}
```

I really appreciate any help... Please let me know if you need more info...

Sincerely,
Farley

Comment: These timers are periodic. You *have* to call `KillTimer()` for them to stop.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, my question was unclear. I meant the callback is being called again and again IMMEDIATELY (not every ten seconds.)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and thereby avoid any scope for confusion

Comment: Will attempt to do so this evening.

Comment: There is a whopper of a bug in your message loop, it does not check the return value of PeekMessage().  So the first WM_TIMER you get will work.  And then PeekMessage() returns FALSE, which you don't see, and you'll dispatch the message over and over again.  The Sleep(50) call is pretty evil as well btw.

Comment: Please also remove the `(TIMERPROC)` cast. If you declared `TimerProc` correctly, the cast should not be necessary.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, you're right. Will remove it.

Comment: @HansPassant You nailed the whopper of a bug, it works now, thanks! But can you elaborate on the Sleep(50) call being "pretty evil"? I don't understand... I want to call the update functions approximately (doesn't have to be exactly) 18 times a second. Is there a better or more correct way to accomplish this? I'd really appreciate any elaboration. Thanks!

Comment: The `Sleep()` means that your program processes at most 20 messages per second. It also means that it will take 50ms to respond to any new messages. You should never `Sleep` on the UI thread. If you want to update ever 50ms, then create another timer to trigger the updates.

Comment: Got it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is happening because you are calling `PeekMessage()` in your message loop instead of `GetMessage()`.

`PeekMessage()` will return `FALSE` if there are no messages in the queue. I don't know what the implementation of `PeekMessage()` is, but I could see it leaving the contents of the `msg` parameter alone if there are no messages in the queue. This means that when `PeekMessage()` returns `FALSE`, `msg` will contain the previous message in the queue. `msg` is then blindly passed to `DispatchMessage()`, which then dutifully will pass that to your window's window procedure. So as long as the `WM_TIMER` message is the last processed message, your  timer callback will be called until another message is added to the queue.

You can fix this by using a more traditional message loop:

```
BOOL bRet;

while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, nullptr, 0, 0 )) != 0)
{ 
    if (bRet == -1)
    {
        // handle the error and possibly exit
    }
    else
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }

    pSCObj->Update();
    manager.Update();
}
```

(Message loop adapted from the sample in the [GetMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation.)

Since `GetMessage()` will block until there is a message in the queue, you don't need to call `Sleep()`, and your process will not use any CPU when there is nothing for it to do.

Comment: I always use the same message loop in all my programs so I don't even pay attention to it anymore :) The `Sleep(50)` shoud have been a good warning though. +1

Comment: Do keep in mind that this is not a functional replacement, the Update() methods are not called nearly enough.  Using PeekMessage() is fine, ignoring the return value is not.

Comment: @Hans that's fair. Was just trying to give a minimal example to get the asker started.

Comment: This code works perfectly: 

       // Main message loop:
         while (true)
         {
           if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
           if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;
        
              if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
           {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
           }
          }
    
          //UPDATES
          pSCObj->Update();
          manager.Update();
          Sleep(50);
         }

Comment: @lequinne can you edit your post to include the code that works for you? (or add an answer to your question). Posting more than a line of code in comments is hard to read (especially when not formatted).

Comment: Will do, sorry, I'm pretty new to this.

Farley

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that the return value of PeekMessage() is not checked. On each loop, if there is no new message, PeekMessage leaves the contents of msg unchanged, and it is simply dispatched again.

Dispatching the messages only when PeekMessage() returns true fixes the problem:

```
    while (true)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;    

            if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }

        //UPDATES
        pSCObj->Update();
        manager.Update();
        Sleep(50);
    }
```